# Oracle. Загрузка при помощи sqlldr (direct path load). Работает ли откат при ошибке?

Tags: oracle

Грузим большие объемы (порядка 500 тыс. записей) каждые 5 минут с помощью sqlldr в секционированную таблицу. Секции по часам, плюс есть еще подсекции (12 штук).
Контрол файл:

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT=TRUE, ERRORS=500000)
UNRECOVERABLE
load data
infile '{FILENAME}'
append
into table TBL_NAME
fields terminated by '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
)
```

Иногда возникает deadlock. При этом обнаружили непонятную проблему. Ожидаем, что при возникновении ошибки Oracle должен выполнить rollback всех загруженных строк. Но проверка данных в целевой таблице показала, что данные не откатились, а были загружены.

Как такое можно объяснить? По окончании загрузки в лог файле видим:

```
SQL*Loader-925: Error while uldlgs: OCIStmtExecute (ptc_hp)
ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.

Table TBL_NAME:
   0 Rows successfully loaded.
   0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
   0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
   0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

   Date conversion cache disabled due to overflow (default size: 1000)
```

Comment: AUTOCOMMIT стоит?

Comment: А где именно это можно глянуть? В контрол файле не стоит.

Comment: Прям в коде sql пишете

  SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF

Comment: @Smithson Это sql loader. у него нет никакого SQL кода и никакого аутокоммита

Comment: Где писать? В контрол файле? Насколько я понимаю, автокоммит в sqlldr по умолчанию. И управлять частотой коммита можно только через опцию ROWS. Не пришлете ссылочку, где про "SET AUTOCOMMIT OFF" для SQL Loader есть информация.

Comment: @kseregal Smithson похоже не понял о чем идет речь. На сколько я понимаю, для быстрой загрузки sql*loader (или ядро оракла по его специальному запросу) готовит страницы данных и сбрасывает их напрямую в датафайлы. понятия транзакции для него не существует. страница либо записана либо нет. и подозреваю, что в rollback сегменты он вообще ничего не пишет, так что откат невозможен. и боюсь кроме как rows управлять не чем.

Comment: Mike, мы сначала тоже заподозрили такое поведение, но в доках пишут следующее If you are performing a direct path load into multiple partitions and a space error occurs, the load is rolled back to the last commit point. If there was no commit point, then the entire load is rolled back. This ensures that no data encountered after the space error is written out to a different partition.
You can use the ROWS parameter to specify the frequency of the commit points. If the ROWS parameter is not specified, the entire load is rolled back.

Comment: [ссылка](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_modes.htm) - здесь пишут

Comment: И что происходит если поставить ROWS заведомо больше чем загружаемых данных и поставить ERRORS=0 что бы он откатывал сразу, как только встретит ошибку

Comment: Не знаю. ROWS это ведь количество отвергнутых записей? Или я ошибаюсь. А ошибка deadlock, а не отвергнутая запись. У нас специально стоит большое число в параметре ERRORS, т.к. бывают единичные отвергнутые записи и при этом нам важно, чтобы файл прогрузился.

Comment: Опытным путем выяснили, что при таком конфиге ролбека нет. Всё что упало в БД до ошибки остается в БД. Вот так. Хотя по идее коммита еще никакого не было.

Answer (score 4):

Нет, отката (*rollback*), в привычном понимании этого термина, с установленой опцией `direct=true` [SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144) не производит.

*Direct path load* не пишет, ни *UNDO*, ни (по умолчанию) *redo logs*.
Загружаемые данные подготавливаются в буфере и пишутся напрямую в *datafile*, используя не отформатированные блоки поверх *HWM (high-water-mark*).

При возникновении ошибки (errors=0) или, если порог допостимых ошибок превышен (errors>0), SQL*Loader прерывает загрузку, но все уже загруженые страницы сохранятся. Подробнее о прерывании загрузки в секции [Interrupted Loads](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-C4FC7240-A461-4C03-A984-81D045DEE939).

Воиспроводимый пример для наглядности. Попробуем записать `null` в колонку с ограничением `not null`:

```
create table stage (id number, item varchar (32), created date)
    partition by range (created) 
    interval (numToDsInterval (1, 'day'))
    (
        partition stage_p1 values less than (date'2018-06-21')
    )
;
```

Генеририруем 100 записей данных с `null` в 66 строке:

```
insert into stage 
    select rownum, 
    case when rownum<>66 then 'item '||rownum end, date'2018-06-20'+rownum/24
    from xmltable ('1 to 100');  

$ sqlplus -l -s user/pass@localhost/db1 <<EOF
    set colsep ';' pages 0 feedback off termout off
    spool items.dat
    select * from stage;
    spool off
EOF
     1;item 1                          ;20180620T010000
     2;item 2                          ;20180620T020000
...
   100;item 100                        ;20180624T040000
```

Установим ограничение:

```
truncate table stage; 
alter table stage modify (item varchar2 (32) not null);
```

В контроль-файл установим: прервать по первой ошибке, страница - 30 записей:

```
options (direct=true, rows=30, errors=0)
load data
truncate
into table stage
fields terminated by ';' (
    id,
    item "trim (:item)",
    created
    )
```

Запускаем загрузку:

```
$ sqlldr user/pass@localhost/db1 control=items.ctl

Path used:      Direct
Save data point reached - logical record count 30.
Save data point reached - logical record count 60.

Load completed - logical record count 90.

Table STAGE:
  65 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file: items.log for more information about the load.
```

Заметьте, *[Save data point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-conventional-and-direct-loads.html#GUID-2562DE31-8745-40B0-AF3B-90048E5146A8) reached*, а не *Commit data point reached*.

В лог файле видно, что первая, вторая и частично (до ошибочной записи) третья страницы сохранились, и на этом SQL*Loader прервал загрузку:

```
Control File:   items.ctl
Data File:      items.dat
  Bad File:     items.bad
  Discard File:  none specified

 (Allow all discards)

Number to load: ALL
Number to skip: 0
Errors allowed: 0
Continuation:    none specified
Path used:      Direct

Table STAGE, loaded from every logical record.
Insert option in effect for this table: TRUNCATE

   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
ID                                  FIRST     *   ;       CHARACTER
ITEM                                 NEXT     *   ;       CHARACTER
    SQL string for column : "trim (:item)"
CREATED                              NEXT     *   ;       CHARACTER

Record 66: Rejected - Error on table STAGE.
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DB"."STAGE"."ITEM")

Specify SKIP=66 when continuing the load.

MAXIMUM ERROR COUNT EXCEEDED - Above statistics reflect partial run.

Table STAGE:
  65 Rows successfully loaded.
  1 Row not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

  Date cache:
   Max Size:      1000
   Entries :        60
   Hits    :         0
   Misses  :         0

  Partition STAGE_P1: 23 Rows loaded.
  Partition SYS_P1116: 24 Rows loaded.
  Partition SYS_P1117: 18 Rows loaded.

Bind array size not used in direct path.
Column array  rows :      30
Stream buffer bytes:  256000
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records rejected:         1
Total logical records discarded:        0
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader main thread:        3
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader load thread:        0

Run began on Thu Jun 21 22:27:38 2018
Run ended on Thu Jun 21 22:27:38 2018

Elapsed time was:     00:00:00.55
CPU time was:         00:00:00.05
```